# Sort DataGridView according particular column before add

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have `DataGridView` that i am adding items via `DataTable`
This items read from XML file and inside this XML file,
those items not sorted and i want to sort is before add to my  `DataGridView`

```
private void UpdateDataGdirView(List<Vendor> list)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("Column1", System.Type.GetType("System.Boolean"));
    dt.Columns.Add("Column2", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("Column3", System.Type.GetType("System.Boolean"));
    dt.Columns.Add("Column4", System.Type.GetType("System.Boolean"));
    dt.Columns.Add("Column5", System.Type.GetType("System.Boolean"));
    dt.Columns.Add("Column6", System.Type.GetType("System.Boolean"));
    DataRow dr;

    foreach (Vendor vendor in list)
    {
        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["Column1"] = vendor.IsVendorChecked;
        dr["Column2"] = vendor.Number;
        dr["Column3"] = vendor.Name;
        dr["Column4"] = vendor.Size;
        dr["Column5"] = vendor.Path;
        dr["Column6"] = vendor.Path2;
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    }

    dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
    dataGridView1.AllowUserToDeleteRows = false;
    dataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
    this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { dataGridView1.DataSource = dt; });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use
dt.defaultview.sort="columnname asc/desc" 
and then bind the datatable to its destination.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use DataView for this. Like :

```
        DataTable orders = dataSet.Tables["SalesOrderHeader"];

        EnumerableRowCollection<DataRow> query =
            from order in orders.AsEnumerable()
            orderby order.Field<decimal>("TotalDue")
            select order;

        DataView view = query.AsDataView();

        bindingSource1.DataSource = view;
```

Follow this link : [Query on DataView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669083.aspx)

OR
You can use like :

```
        DataTable orders = dataSet.Tables["SalesOrderHeader"];
        DataView dv = new DataView(orders);
        dv.Sort = "TotalDue";
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dv;
```

Comment: What does "SalesOrderHeader" and "TotalDue" means ?

Comment: It is just an example, please follow the link i posted.

Comment: BTW "SalesOrderHeader" is a table name in dataSet and "TotalDue"is a column name of "SalesOrderHeader" table.